# How can I round a column in a Spark Dataset?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

using Scala Spark, how can I use the typed Dataset API to round an aggregated column?

Also, how can I retain the type of a dataset through a groupby operation?

This is what I currently have:

```
case class MyRow(
  k1: String,
  k2: String,
  c1: Double,
  c2: Double
)

def groupTyped(ds: Dataset[MyRow]): Dataset[MyRow] = {
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.scalalang.typed._
ds.groupByKey(row => (row.k1, row.k2))
  .agg(
    avg(_.c1),
    avg(_.c2)
  )
  .map(r => MyRow(r._1._1, r._1._2, r._2, r._3))
}
```

1. if I replace the `avg(_.c1)` with a `round(avg(_.c1))` I get a type error. What's the correct way to round my values?
2. the `.map(...)` line does not feel right -- is there a more elegant way to retain my Dataset's type?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `round` indeed fails on a type error, because `agg` expects an Aggregate Function of type `TypedColumn[IN, OUT]` and round provides a `Column` (suitable for use on DataFrames).

What you need here is a rounded-average aggregate function, which isn't supplied in `org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.scalalang.typed._` - but you can rather easily create one yourself by extending the class that performs the average aggregation:

```
// Extend TypedAverage - round the result before returning it
class TypedRoundAverage[IN](f: IN => Double) extends TypedAverage[IN](f) {
  override def finish(reduction: (Double, Long)): Double = math.round(super.finish(reduction))
}

// A nice wrapper to create the TypedRoundAverage for a given function  
def roundAvg[IN](f: IN => Double): TypedColumn[IN, Double] = new TypedRoundAverage(f).toColumn

// Now you can use "roundAvg" instead of "round"  
def groupTyped(ds: Dataset[MyRow]): Dataset[MyRow] = {
  ds.groupByKey(row => (row.k1, row.k2))
    .agg(
      roundAvg(_.c1),
      roundAvg(_.c2)
    )
    .map { case ((k1, k2), c1, c2) => MyRow(k1, k2, c1, c2) } // just a nicer way to put it
}
```

I can't see a way to get rid of the `map` operation, as the group-by necessarily returns a tuple, but it can be made a bit nicer using pattern matching

Answer (score 9):

While accepted answer works and is more general, in this case you can also use round. You just need to make column typed after rounding using `.as[T]` (also defining type to avg becomes necessary).

```
.agg(
  // Alternative ways to define a type to avg
  round(avg((r: MyRow) => r.c1)).as[Double],
  round(avg[MyRow](_.c2)).as[Double]
)
```